# SOLR: How do I query SOLR *externally* in PHP after Drupal has indexed it?

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-6, solr

I'm building a small class in PHP that talks to Apache SOLR and fetches a cached query of data. This is a stand-alone script that will be called outside of Drupal. The data is a query associated with a content_type defined in Drupal 6.

I did this initially by defining things in the code below. Now, however, I'm required to index everything via the Drupal ApacheSOLR module.

I'd like to know how to query SOLR for a certain query *WITHOUT* using the Drupal SOLR module.

When I was doing this completely outside of Drupal, I would create an entry in the data-config found in solr's /conf directory, as follows:

```
<document name="content">
    <entity name="id"
        query="SELECT e.nid, e.field_a, e.field_b, e.field_c, n.type AS content_type

        FROM
            content_type_myContentType e

        LEFT JOIN
            node n ON n.nid = e.nid

        WHERE
            n.status='1'">
        <field column="nid" name="id" />
        <field column="title" name="title" />

        <field column="field_1" name="field_1" />
        <field column="field_2" name="field_2" />
        <field column="content_type" name="content_type" />
    </entity>
</document>
```

And setting the fields up in the schema.xml, like so:

```
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
    <field column="nid" name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
    <field column="field_a" name="field_a" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field column="field_b" name="field_b" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field column="field_c" name="field_c" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field column="content_type" name="content_type" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

    <defaultSearchField>fulltext</defaultSearchField>
```

However, now we want Drupal to handle that, so I have configured SOLR to speak with Drupal's apachesolr module. It seems I select the fields I'd like to have indexed in the "enable filters" tab.

Now, assuming I am outside of drupal, and want to query solr for all results of a certain content type, how do I do that? Previously I would call $myConnection->search($query), which still connects fine, but returns empty results.

My old query would be something like:

```
$query = 'content_type: my_content_type_name';
```

Which no longer works as I don't know what Drupal/SOLR is defining my indexed field as. Additionally, how do I define a query? Can I still do that via the data-config.xml, but allow Drupal to be responsible for the indexing?

Comment: What do you mean you don't know what Solr is defining your indexed field as? It's the name you gave it in your field declaration (i.e. field_a). Maybe I didn't get your question. Are you simply asking how to manually craft a Solr query on your own (that is, without the Drupal Apache Solr contrib module)?

Comment: Yes, where Drupal is configuring/indexing everything via the apachesolr module, but then I am referencing this outside of Drupal. I need to avoid bootstrapping Drupal every time I poll solr with ajax, so I'm using php and curl to manually poll SOLR. Turns out it was a corrupt index, causing my expected fields to display no results. Because I was previously caching a query when I did it manually, it was a different process to configure the fields.